# Non performance-related settings to be included in a options menu

Tags: game-design, user-experience

What settings, not necessarly resource-intensive, should be included in 3D first person puzzle game to give the average player a good experience?

I'm thinking about:

- Mouse sensitivity
- Remapping of key bindings
- Different audio volume settings (music, effects, dialogs...)

Is there something else that should be included?

Comment: The question is too broad to give a concrete answer. But.. you can just try out 5-7 games similar to yours and look at what and how they did.

Comment: Totally depends on what your game has to offer. Can you link it to an account (fb, google, etc) -> unlink option. Can you export/ import save games? Language would be another point. This is something you can copy from others, there is no need to reinvent it, it does not even need to be a puzzle game to get a general impression what option menues contain

Comment: Looking to other games doesn't tell me much since usually there are big companies behind and they just provide everything is possible. I only need what an average player usually want to adjust, thought that game designer out there had this concept pretty clear. Thanks for advice @Kromster.

Comment: Thanks @Zibelas, import/export and language seemes to be good options to add. I'll try too look into other games but as I said they provide too much and is not easy to have clear what's a "must-have" so to keep the interface as simpler I can.

Comment: Usually it is the smaller open-source games that *"provide everything is possible"*, for example look at OpenTTD options menu. Big companies usually know what they are doing, employ playtests and provide what makes good sense )

Comment: From my experience many small games I played didn't even provided a options menu. Of course OpenTTD is not the case but is a perfect example of a videogame I shouldn't imitate while building my options menu, that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: Keep in mind that the more you add options, the more time you'll need to spend implementing those and the longer it'll take before you can release your game. I suggest you focus on the game, release it, then wait for your player base to request those features.

Comment: @Vaillancourt that's a good point, thanks for suggestion. I'm focused on the game and the main mechanics are almost complete, I would like to understand how to design a good game, not necessarly including those settings in my current game. I'll look for feedback after the realease too, that's for sure the better way to understand what players want.